# Structure of software javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to programming in JavaFX,
I have the main controller in the file BodyController.java fron this i load FXML with two other drivers.

RightPanel.java and InsertClient.java

If I'm in  method of InsertClient.java controller how i can access to the methods of RightPanel.java

Regards

Comment: tried using references?

Comment: @JacksonMireski can you write an example please?

Comment: `import FOLDER.FILEJAVA;`